# Creating Slackbot with Google Sheets integration using python and git

Tags: python, git, google-sheets

My name is Ken. I am trying to create a Slack Bot first one message every Monday at 9:00 am and asks for a input (goal number of sales for the week). Then responds with user input in new message saying (great your weekly sales goal is (#). Then it takes this number and adds it to Google sheets. Then asks user to enter daily goal for the day. And responds with (daily goal set as). Then at 9:00 pm asks user to input the number of deals written and keeps track of all data in Google sheets and provides graphs. I have been thinking maybe MySQL would work for that too.

Here is some of the code I have so far: 
starterbot.py

```
import os
import time
from slackclient import slackclient

# starterbot's ID as an environment variable
BOT_ID = os.environ.get("BOT_ID")

# contasts
AT_BOT = "<@" + BOT_ID + ">"
EXAMPLE_COMMAND = "do"


#instantiate Slack & Twilio clients
slack_client = SlackClient(os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'))


def handle_command (command, channel)
     """
        Receives commnds directed at the bot and determines if they
        are valid commands. if so, then acts on the commands. if not, 
        returns back what it needs for clarification.
     """
     response = "Not sure what you mean. Use the *" + EXAMPLE_COMMAND + \
                "* command with numbers, delimited by spaces."
                if command.startswitch(EXAMPLE_COMMAND):
                    response = "Sure ... wire some more c ie then I can do 
that!"
                slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=channel,
                                        text=response, as_user=True)


def parse_slack_output(slack_messages):
    """
        The Slack Real Time Messaging API is an event firehose. 
        this parsing function returns None unless a message is 
        directed at the Bot, based on its ID.
    """


    if slack_messages and len(slack_messages) > 0;
        for message in slack_messages:
            if message and 'text' in message and AT_BOT in message['text']:

                command = message['text'].split(AT_BOT)[1].strip().lower()
                channel = message['channel']
                # return text after the @ mention, white space removed
                return command, channel

    return None, None




if __name__ == "__main__":
    READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY = 1 # 1 second delay between reading from firehose
    if slack_client.rtm_connect():
        print("starterbot connected and running!")
        while True:
            command, channel = parse_slack_output(slack_client.rtm_read())
            if command and channel:
                handle_command(command, channel)
            time.sleep(READ_WEBSOCKET_DELAY)
else: 
    print("Connection failed. Invalid Slack token or bot ID?")
```

bot_id_py

```
import os
from slackclient import SlackClient
import pdb


BOT_NAME = 'pilot4u'

slack_client = SlackClient(os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_call = slack_client.api_call("users.list")
if api_call.get('members'):
        pdb.set_trace()
       # Retrieve all users so we can find our bot
       users = api_call.get('members')
       for user in users:
            if 'name' in user and user.get('name') == BOT_NAME:
                print("Bot ID for '" + user ['name'] + "'is " + 
 user.get('id'))
else: 
    print("could not find bot user with the name " + BOT_NAME)
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: im trying to implement a wait function where the bot detects the timezone and time.. like say 9:00 am cst. then posts  message at that time.

Comment: You already said what were you trying to do on the question. However, it is missing a description of the problem you are having... Please add that to your question, and people will be able to help you